# Disk Queue length of 30 in Azure App Service, that can't be right

Tags: hard-drive, azure, performance-monitoring, azure-web-apps

We are having a battle with the Microsoft Azure support team. I hope the Serverfault community can chime in as the support team has messed us about before.

Here is what is happening.

As part of a larger SaaS service that we host on Azure, we have a front-end App Service that accepts basic HTTP requests, carries out some minor validation and then passes the grunt work on to a back-end server. This process is not CPU,  memory or network intensive and we don't touch the disk subsystem at all.

The pricing tier is 'Basic: 2 Medium', which is more than sufficient for the load we put on it. The CPU and Memory charts show that the system is largely sleeping with memory usage being around 36%.

As we paid good attention in server school, we actively monitor the various layers of the overall solution using Azure's standard monitoring facilities. One of the counters we keep track of is the 'Disk Queue length', it is one of the very few counters available on Azure App Services so it must be important.

Back in server school we were told that the disk queue length should ideally be zero and if it is persistently above 1, you need to get your act together (There are some exceptions for certain RAID configurations). Over the last few years all was well, the disk queue length was zero 99% of the time with the occasional spike to 5 when Microsoft was servicing the system.

A couple of months ago things started to change out of the blue (so not after we rolled out changes). Disk queue alerts started flooding in and the average queue length is in the 30s.

We let it run for a few days to see if the problem would go away (performance is not noticeably impacted, at least not under the current load). As the problem did not go away we thought that perhaps the underlying system had a problem so we instantiated a brand new Azure App Service and migrated to that one. Same problem.

[image: Disk Queue Length for a typical week]

So we reached out to Azure support. Naturally they asked us to run a number of nonsense tests in the hope we would go away (they asked for network traces... for a disk queue problem!). We don't give up so easily, so we ran their nonsense tests and eventually were told to just set the alert for the queue length to 50 (over 10 minutes).

Although we have no control over the underlying hardware, infrastructure and system configuration, this just does not sound right.

Their full response is as follows

> I reached out to our product team with the information gathered in
>   this case.
>
> They investigated the issues where the alert you have specified for
>   Disk Queue Length is firing more frequently than expected.
>
> This alert is set to notify you if the Disk Queue Length average
>   exceeded 10 over 5 minutes.  This metric is the average number of both
>   read and write requests that were queued for the selected disk during
>   the sample interval. For the Azure App Service Infrastructure this
>   metric is discussed in the following documentation link:
>   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-monitor
>
> The value of 10 is very low for any type of application deployed and
>   so you may be seeing false positives. This means the alert might
>   trigger more frequently than the exact number of connections.
>
> For example on each virtual machine we run an Anti-Malware Service to
>   protect the Azure App Service infrastructure. During these times you
>   will see connections made and if the alert is set to a low number it
>   can be triggered.
>
> We did not identify any instance of this Anti-Malware scanning
>   affecting your site availability. Microsoft recommends that you
>   consider increasing the Disk Queue Length metric be set to an average
>   value of at least 50 over 10 minutes.
>
> We believe this value should allow you to continue to monitor your
>   application for performance purposes. It should also be less affected
>   by the Anti-Malware scanning or other connections we run for
>   maintenance purposes.

Anyone wants to chime in?

Comment: I also see random spikes on this metric into the hundreds from time to time. The spikes usually stay under 500, but this morning it went up to 5K. This is on an app service plan that runs web jobs only to process service bus messages. I.e. No disk work.

Comment: Perhaps worth for you to open a support case via the Azure Portal as well. The more customers mentioning it, the more likely it is it will be escalated. We have been through this with Azure support before. Eventually it always gets 'magically' sorted though, but you have to be persistent.

Comment: This may also be related to SWAP usage on the machines, you could check that - seems like the I/O backend is the fault here, but lowering the swap usage should help lower down the AQL on the storage.

Comment: Thanks @bocian85, but the system is not under any memory pressure (In my question it states 35%), and we are seeing disk queue length issues at times that our software is not processing any requests.

Comment: You could inspect the servers from the console using for example `atop` and see what really makes the writes, the biggest cannon to debug such thing is the `sysdig`, but it might be an overkill sometimes and bring more harm than good. All in all it's seems to be Azure's fault coming from and overbooked storage nad only they can do anything about it in the long run.

Comment: `atop` is Linux right? This question is about a Windows Azure App Service. There is no desktop access or the ability run Linux commands. Anyway, I have escalated this back to the Azure support team, let's see what they come back with.

Comment: @op what ended up being the resolution?

Comment: @JasonCoder Microsoft support stopped responding, but after a while the scale of the graph was mysteriously changed and the figure has been 'around 2' ever since. When I chart the period where I got the crazy figures, it also shows 'around 2'. My guess is that they were measuring correctly, but not charting correctly. I have no idea what the current figure means, and no one is willing or able to explain.

Answer (score 3):

To me, that sounds high as well, with Azure your in a shared pool environment. I bet your back-end disk is getting hammered by other clients. Based on other posts it sounds like Azure is known for this. I would see if they can relocate your backend disk to less used storage or try the recommendations in these posts or others.

[Performance azure disks, high average queue length](https://serverfault.com/questions/704309/performance-azure-disks-high-average-queue-length?rq=1)

[Azure IO performance](https://serverfault.com/questions/592560/azure-io-performance?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: We already moved to a completely new App Service, which is unlikely to be the same physical system although there is no way for us to know. I haven't seen any real answers yet, so will keep pushing Azure support until it gets escalated.

Comment: Not really the definitive answer I was hoping for, but I'd hate to see the bounty go to waste, so here you go!